# Force a Linux kernel module to be compiled as a module instead of built-in

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, embedded-linux

I have the [sources of the kernel of an embedded Linux box](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qosgpl/files/QNAP%20NAS%20GPL%20Source/GPL_QTS_4.1.1_1003.tar.gz/download) (specifically a QNAP NAS) which is running a 64-bit v3.12.6 Linux kernel, together with the kernel config files.

What I'm trying to do is adding DVB support to that kernel, by adding kernel modules which I can then add to the system using **insmod**. However, using this version, I'm unable to compile **dvb-core.ko** which is only available built-in (i.e. **CONFIG_DVB_CORE=y** instead of **CONFIG_DVB_CORE=m**).

I've looked at the config file that's related to my box model and there are no DVB config switches set:

```
# cat ../../kernel_cfg/TS-X53/linux-3.12.6-x86_64-hal.cfg | grep DVB
# CONFIG_DVB_DUMMY_FE is not set
```

So I've copied that file as **.config** in the kernel sources directory and run **make menuconfig**. I checked the option:

```
Device Drivers -> Multimedia Support -> Digital TV Support
```

It's not possible to hit **M** on that line so I hit **Y**; and after enabling it, if I search for *DVB_CORE* (using the **/** key), I get:

```
---------------------------- Search Results -----------------------------
| Symbol: DVB_CORE [=y]                                                 |  
| Type  : tristate                                                      |  
|   Defined at drivers/media/Kconfig:117                                |  
|   Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y] && MEDIA_DIGITAL_TV_SUPPORT [=y]     |  
|   Selects: CRC32 [=y]                                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So if then I enable the various tuner drivers as a module (such as *dvb-usb-dib0700.ko*), save, exit and then run **make modules**, I get all the tuner **.ko** files but not **dvb-core.ko** which is necessary to my system to load the other dependent **.ko** files. These are the config switches after exiting:

```
# cat .config | grep DVB
CONFIG_DVB_CORE=y
CONFIG_DVB_NET=y
CONFIG_DVB_MAX_ADAPTERS=8
# CONFIG_DVB_DYNAMIC_MINORS is not set
CONFIG_DVB_USB=m
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_A800 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIBUSB_MB is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIBUSB_MC is not set
CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIB0700=m
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_UMT_010 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_CXUSB is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_M920X is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIGITV is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_VP7045 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_VP702X is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_GP8PSK is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_NOVA_T_USB2 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_TTUSB2 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DTT200U is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_OPERA1 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_AF9005 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_PCTV452E is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DW2102 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_CINERGY_T2 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DTV5100 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_FRIIO is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_AZ6027 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_TECHNISAT_USB2 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_V2 is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_TTUSB_BUDGET is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_TTUSB_DEC is not set
# CONFIG_DVB_B2C2_FLEXCOP_USB is not set
# DVB-S (satellite) frontends
# DVB-T (terrestrial) frontends
CONFIG_DVB_DIB3000MC=m
CONFIG_DVB_DIB7000M=m
CONFIG_DVB_DIB7000P=m
# DVB-C (cable) frontends
CONFIG_DVB_LGDT3305=m
CONFIG_DVB_S5H1411=m
CONFIG_DVB_DIB8000=m
CONFIG_DVB_TUNER_DIB0070=m
CONFIG_DVB_TUNER_DIB0090=m
# SEC control devices for DVB-S
# CONFIG_DVB_DUMMY_FE is not set
```

If I edit the **.config** file manually and put **CONFIG_DVB_CORE=m** save and then **make modules** nothing changes:

```
# make modules
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `relocs'.
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 195 modules
```

The **dvb-core.ko** is still not compiled, and also the setting is reverted:

```
# cat .config | grep DVB_CORE
CONFIG_DVB_CORE=y
```

So my question is: how can I compile **dvb-core.ko** as a kernel module?

Be aware that using the [previous kernel sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qosgpl/files/QNAP%20NAS%20GPL%20Source/GPL_TS-20140513-4.1.0.tar.gz/download), which were using kernel 3.4.6, I could do this easily with the **make menuconfig** as there I was able to set **M** on the DVB setting. But the menu was different as DVB was here:

```
Device Drivers -> Multimedia Support -> DVB for Linux
```

And this was the result of the search for *DVB_CORE*:

```
---------------------------- Search Results -----------------------------
| Symbol: DVB_CORE [=m]                                                 |  
| Type  : tristate                                                      |  
| Prompt: DVB for Linux                                                 |  
|   Defined at drivers/media/Kconfig:69                                 |  
|   Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y]                                      |  
|   Location:                                                           |  
|     -> Device Drivers                                                 |  
|       -> Multimedia support (MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y])                      |  
|   Selects: CRC32 [=y]                                                 |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the (old) config switches:

```
# cat .config | grep DVB
CONFIG_DVB_CORE=m
CONFIG_DVB_NET=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_BT848_DVB=y
CONFIG_DVB_MAX_ADAPTERS=8
# CONFIG_DVB_DYNAMIC_MINORS is not set
CONFIG_DVB_CAPTURE_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_DVB_AV7110=m
# CONFIG_DVB_AV7110_OSD is not set
CONFIG_DVB_BUDGET_CORE=m
CONFIG_DVB_BUDGET=m
CONFIG_DVB_BUDGET_CI=m
CONFIG_DVB_BUDGET_AV=m
CONFIG_DVB_BUDGET_PATCH=m
CONFIG_DVB_USB=m
# CONFIG_DVB_USB_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_DVB_USB_A800=m
CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIBUSB_MB=m
CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIBUSB_MB_FAULTY=y
CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIBUSB_MC=m
CONFIG_DVB_USB_DIB0700=m
... cut ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was easy to apply, but not so easy to guess.
To build **dvb-core.ko** as a module, I had to go back on the menu:

```
Device Drivers -> Multimedia support
```

There, **Multimedia support** was already marked as **Y** by the kernel configuration file:

```
<*> Multimedia Support --->
```

The solution is selecting **Multimedia Support** and pressing **M** to mark it as a module:

```
<M> Multimedia Support --->
```

So basically the module selection has to be done **on the parent menu**, while I initially tought it was on *Digital TV Support*.
Then when searching for *DVB_CORE* I correctly get:

```
---------------------------- Search Results -----------------------------
| Symbol: DVB_CORE [=m]                                                 |  
| Type  : tristate                                                      |  
|   Defined at drivers/media/Kconfig:117                                |  
|   Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=m] && MEDIA_DIGITAL_TV_SUPPORT [=y]     |  
|   Selects: CRC32 [=y]                                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```